# How to install Nodemon via Terminal on Mac

Tags: macos, installation, terminal, nodemon

I'm trying to install Nodemon via terminal by typing:

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

But my terminal throws the following error:

```
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nodemon'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ayrix/.npm/_logs/2022-12-15T18_50_01_089Z-debug-0.log
```

Does anyone has an idea how I can change the permisson to install the utility?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It didn't take long to figure it out though.

I just had to type the `sudo` command infront like

```
 sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

I think it's still worth to keep that post in case that someone else faces the same issue.